# Unable to use login method in django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to use the Login method to log in a user who is validated from an external API.

```
def whmcs_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username1 = request.POST['username'];
        password1 = request.POST['password'];
        whmcs1 = whmcs()
        login = whmcs1.login(username1=username1,password1=password1)
        if login['result'] == 'success':
            userid = login['userid']
            try:
                whmcs_i = Profile.objects.get(whmcsid=userid)
                user = User.objects.get(id=whmcs_i.user_id)
                user.backend = 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
                login(request, user)
            except Profile.DoesNotExist:
                whmcs_data = whmcs1.getuser(userid=userid)
                user = User.objects.create(username='random', 
                    password='33e32121',                    
                    first_name=whmcs_data['firstname'],                   
                    last_name=whmcs_data['lastname'])
                user.profile.whmcsid = userid
                user.save()
                user.backend = 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
                login(request, user)
```

I keep getting the following error when ever I use the login method
"'dict' object is not callable"

Traceback

> File "/Volumes/Development/ssb-panel/ssbenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
>       response = get_response(request)
>
> File "/Volumes/Development/ssb-panel/ssbenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 249, in _legacy_get_response
>       response = self._get_response(request)
>
> File "/Volumes/Development/ssb-panel/ssbenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
>       response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
> File "/Volumes/Development/ssb-panel/ssbenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
>       response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> File "/Volumes/Development/ssb-panel/SSBpanel/main/views.py", line 55, in whmcs_login
>       login(request, user)
>   TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable

Fixed. Variable name mismatch. Had made a dict named login due to which I wasn't able to use the login method of Django.

Comment: You have a stack trace as well?

Comment: Since `login` is of `dict` type the error is occuring in the line `login(request, user)` where you actually handle the `login` dict as a callable. What the `whmcs1.login(username1=username1,password1=password1)` returns is a `dict`.

Comment: Yes, [link](http://prntscr.com/f2hggb)

Comment: @nik_m I didn't get you

Comment: The `whmcs1.login(username1=username1,password1=password1)` function returns a variable of type `dict`. So, `login` is a dictionary. So, you access it like this `login['result']`, `login['userid']` etc. But in the line `login(request, user)` (where the error occurs) you're trying to call the function with the name `login`, where the `login` is not a function (callable) but a dictionary!

Comment: @nik_m just noticed that now as well. Damn thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @GauravJagtap better if you paste the traceback in your question. That image might disappear in the future.